# How do I implement getWindowManager() in Asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, window-managers

For some reason, I want to get user's phone information in my asynctask function.

here is my asynctask code

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
@Override

protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
    ...my code
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //Do anything with response..
}

private  String getWeith(String url) {  
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();  
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);  
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;  
    String w=new String(""+width);
    String h=new String(""+height);
    url=url+"&23=w%3A"+w+"%20h%3A"+h+"%20d%3A"; 
    return url;
}  
}
```

error message show that  "The method  getWindowManager()  is undefined for the type RequestTask."

but I've try to import everything I know...
And this "getWeith()" function can work on my mainactivity.
Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Reason for error

`getWindowManager()` is a method on `Activity` not on an `AsyncTask` so you will get the error "The method getWindowManager() is undefined for the type RequestTask.".

> How to fix it?

In order to get this method inside  AsyncTask use `getSystemService()` to retrieve a `WindowManager` then do you task.

See this [documentation of WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html)

Answer (score 3):

You're extending `AsyncTask`, which doesn't have the method [getWindowManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). You need access to the object for which this method is defined.

So, try passing your activity to your `RequestTask` object, and calling `getWindowManager()` on that activity.